# How to change Apache Tomcat web server port number

Tags: tomcat, port

How to change Apache Tomcat web server default port number?

---

I am developing a web application in JSP, in that for some purpose I need to change tomcat accessing port. Is there any possibility?

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/how-to-change-tomcat-default-port/

Comment: @Brain Sure, thank u your suggestion, i got the anawer..

Comment: Question is off topic and has nothing to do with JSPs whatsoever.

Comment: This might help you http://www.digizol.com/2008/06/tomcat-how-to-change-port-8080.html

Answer (score 230, accepted):

Simple !!... you can do it easily via server.xml

- Go to ***`tomcat>conf`*** folder
- Edit `server.xml`
- Search "**Connector port"**
- Replace "8080" by `your port number`
- Restart tomcat server.

You are done!.

Comment: In windows usually, the tomcat config folder is located at "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\conf"

Comment: If I change to 8081, it works perfectly, but if i change to 80, it did not work at all. Googled a few solutions, no one worked, any idea? I am using Apache 9 & Ubuntu 18. Thanks

Answer (score 25):

Navigate to /tomcat-root/conf folder. Within you will find the server.xml file.

Open the server.xml in your preferred editor. Search the below similar statement (not exactly  same as below will differ)

```
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" 
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

Going to give the port number to 9090

```
     <Connector port="9090" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" 
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

Save the file and restart the server.
Now the tomcat will listen at port 9090

Answer (score 6):

You need to edit the `Tomcat/conf/server.xml` and change the connector port. The connector setting should look something like this:

```
<Connector port="8080" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
           maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
           enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100"
           connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true" />
```

Just change the connector port from default 8080 to another valid port number.

Answer (score 6):

1) Locate server.xml in {Tomcat installation folder}\ conf \
2) Find following similar statement

```
       <!-- Define a non-SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8180 -->
      <Connector port="8080" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
           maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
           enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100"
           connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true" />
```

For example

```
<Connector port="8181" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" 
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

Edit and save the server.xml file. Restart Tomcat. Done

Further reference:
**http://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/how-to-change-tomcat-default-port/**