# how to redirect my application URL running on tomcat 8080 port to the domain www.xyz.com

Tags: java, .htaccess, tomcat, amazon-s3

I have an application running on tomcat server of amazon AWS machine. when I enter

> 52.38.46.xx:8080/xxxxxx

it is working fine, and now i wanted the same to be running when i enter the domain name like

> `www.xyz.com.`

The domain hosting is with `amazon route53`, i tried with lots of solutions by installing `httpd` and including `.htacces`s in `"/var/www/html"` after changing the configurations in httpd.conf file from  `AllowOverride None` to  `AllowOverride All` but in vain. I tried configuring `s3bucket` by mentioning the url path in the redirect all requests to another host name which works fine but the problem is the original URL is being displayed. I need to hide the original URL and access only through the domain name.

Solution for this is much appreciated,

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Run tomcat server on Port 80 by changing the port from "8080" to "80" in server.xml file 
and deploy your application at the root in tomcat

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18415603/6309882

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5328636/6309882