# Port 8080 required by Tomcat v8.0 Server at localhost is already in use

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I download tomcat on eclipse and it was working fine. but 1 month later I tryed to run it again and I got an error for some reason

**ERROR:**
Port 8080 required by Tomcat v8.0 Server at localhost is already in use. The server may already be running in another process, or a system process may be using the port. To start this server you will need to stop the other process or change the port number(s).

**What I have tried:**

Seem to be tomcat is already running...

**#1:** I tried going on http://localhost:8080/ but I dont got a welcome screen but I get a login in popup... I didn't have a username or password
[image]

**#2:**  I click on startup.bat -> shutdown.bat -> run tomcat in eclipse. but no luck

**#3:** I check the 'Task Manager' but didn't see Tomcat.exe running.

**#4:** I tried the netstat command and I got the following results. than I use the taskkill... maybe I use the wrong taskkill id. can some one double check it?

```
C:\Users\dave>netstat -aon

Active Connections

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State           PID
  TCP    0.0.0.0:135            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       1320
  TCP    0.0.0.0:445            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
  TCP    0.0.0.0:1521           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       3100
  TCP    0.0.0.0:1522           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4024
  TCP    0.0.0.0:5500           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4024
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8080           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       3100
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49664          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       1044
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49665          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       1676
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49666          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       688
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49667          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       2380
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49671          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       1116
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49687          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       1148
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49697          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       3220
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49705          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4208
  TCP    127.0.0.1:1522         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4024
  TCP    127.0.0.1:1522         127.0.0.1:49706        ESTABLISHED     4024
  TCP    127.0.0.1:2031         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4040
  TCP    127.0.0.1:5037         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       11028
  TCP    127.0.0.1:5354         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       2976
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49668        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       2868
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49674        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       3100
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49706        127.0.0.1:1522         ESTABLISHED     4208
  TCP    192.168.2.10:139       0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
  TCP    192.168.2.10:11316     0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       6600
  TCP    192.168.2.10:49787     209.10.120.24:80       CLOSE_WAIT      2672
  TCP    192.168.2.10:49917     216.58.219.234:443     ESTABLISHED     9884
  TCP    192.168.2.10:52540     193.85.216.236:80      ESTABLISHED     2672
  TCP    192.168.2.10:52600     65.52.108.205:443      ESTABLISHED     6500
  TCP    192.168.2.10:52619     173.194.66.125:5222    ESTABLISHED     9884
  TCP    192.168.2.10:55224     216.58.219.238:443     ESTABLISHED     8520
  TCP    192.168.2.10:55262     74.125.22.95:443       ESTABLISHED     9884
  TCP    192.168.2.10:55265     74.125.29.91:443       ESTABLISHED     8520
  TCP    192.168.2.10:55266     172.217.4.206:443      ESTABLISHED     8520
  TCP    192.168.2.10:55271     216.58.219.237:443     ESTABLISHED     9884
  TCP    [::]:135               [::]:0                 LISTENING       1320
  TCP    [::]:445               [::]:0                 LISTENING       4
  TCP    [::]:1521              [::]:0                 LISTENING       3100
  TCP    [::]:1522              [::]:0                 LISTENING       4024
  TCP    [::]:5500              [::]:0                 LISTENING       4024
  TCP    [::]:8080              [::]:0                 LISTENING       3100
  TCP    [::]:49664             [::]:0                 LISTENING       1044
  TCP    [::]:49665             [::]:0                 LISTENING       1676
  TCP    [::]:49666             [::]:0                 LISTENING       688
  TCP    [::]:49667             [::]:0                 LISTENING       2380
  TCP    [::]:49671             [::]:0                 LISTENING       1116
  TCP    [::]:49687             [::]:0                 LISTENING       1148
  TCP    [::]:49697             [::]:0                 LISTENING       3220
  TCP    [::]:49705             [::]:0                 LISTENING       4208
  TCP    [::1]:2031             [::]:0                 LISTENING       4040
  TCP    [::1]:49672            [::]:0                 LISTENING       4024
  TCP    [::1]:49955            [::]:0                 LISTENING       1952
  TCP    [fe80::394e:2f21:75ae:9f92%13]:1521  [fe80::394e:2f21:75ae:9f92%13]:49691  ESTABLISHED     3100
  TCP    [fe80::394e:2f21:75ae:9f92%13]:49691  [fe80::394e:2f21:75ae:9f92%13]:1521  ESTABLISHED     3220
  TCP    [fe80::394e:2f21:75ae:9f92%13]:54211  [fe80::394e:2f21:75ae:9f92%13]:54213  ESTABLISHED     3220
  TCP    [fe80::394e:2f21:75ae:9f92%13]:54212  [fe80::394e:2f21:75ae:9f92%13]:54214  ESTABLISHED     3220
  TCP    [fe80::394e:2f21:75ae:9f92%13]:54213  [fe80::394e:2f21:75ae:9f92%13]:54211  ESTABLISHED     3100
  TCP    [fe80::394e:2f21:75ae:9f92%13]:54214  [fe80::394e:2f21:75ae:9f92%13]:54212  ESTABLISHED     3100
  UDP    0.0.0.0:3702           *:*                                    988
  UDP    0.0.0.0:3702           *:*                                    988
  UDP    0.0.0.0:5353           *:*                                    2248
  UDP    0.0.0.0:5355           *:*                                    2248
  UDP    0.0.0.0:49664          *:*                                    2976
  UDP    0.0.0.0:58538          *:*                                    988
  UDP    127.0.0.1:1900         *:*                                    1704
  UDP    127.0.0.1:56478        *:*                                    1704
  UDP    192.168.2.10:137       *:*                                    4
  UDP    192.168.2.10:138       *:*                                    4
  UDP    192.168.2.10:1900      *:*                                    1704
  UDP    192.168.2.10:5353      *:*                                    2976
  UDP    192.168.2.10:11316     *:*                                    6600
  UDP    192.168.2.10:56477     *:*                                    1704
  UDP    [::]:3702              *:*                                    988
  UDP    [::]:3702              *:*                                    988
  UDP    [::]:5353              *:*                                    2248
  UDP    [::]:5355              *:*                                    2248
  UDP    [::]:49665             *:*                                    2976
  UDP    [::]:58539             *:*                                    988
  UDP    [::1]:1900             *:*                                    1704
  UDP    [::1]:56476            *:*                                    1704
  UDP    [fe80::394e:2f21:75ae:9f92%13]:1900  *:*                                    1704
  UDP    [fe80::394e:2f21:75ae:9f92%13]:56475  *:*                                    1704

C:\Users\dave>taskkill /F /PID 3100
ERROR: The process with PID 3100 could not be terminated.
Reason: Access is denied.
```

Comment: why the negative vote? I tried every thing and added all the detail

Comment: You can try to change Tomcat port:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18415578/how-to-change-tomcat-port-number
another example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4756039/how-to-change-the-port-of-tomcat-from-8080-to-80

Comment: I changed to port 9090 but no luck

Comment: Your `netstat` output shows that port `8080` is in use by process `3100`. Look at process `3100` in Task Manager and you'll see what that process is. If you're on Windows 10, you'll see the process id on the Details tab.

Comment: The "Access is denied" from `taskkill` is probably because you're not running the command prompt is admin mode.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on another Stack Exchange site such as "Server Fault" or "SuperUser".

Comment: why the so much hate on this website?

Comment: You are getting authentication prompt which means tomcat running outside Eclipse somewhere. Find all Tomcat installations on your machine!

Answer (score 1):

I can quickly think of 2 possibilities from your question/comments -

> 1. You have installed tomcat at two different locations (1 used by Eclipse and other tomcat source) Usually developers download tomcat to
>      run standalone Java applications irrespective of IDEs.
> 2. process `javaw.exe (OR java.exe sometimes)` running in your machine. Also, process might be added in startup programs so every time you
>      start machine, it is started. Try to end this process from task
>      manager and then restart Eclipse. You should get tomcat running.

If none of above works, I insist you to create another Workspace in Eclipse and add tomcat there to run your application.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

> Step 1: (open the CMD command)

```
 C:\Users\username>netstat -o -n -a | findstr 0.0:8080

 TCP 0.0.0.0:3000 0.0.0.0:0 LISTENING 3116

 Now , we can see that LISTENING port is 3116 for 8080 ,

 We need to kill 3116 now
```

> Step 2:-

```
 C:\Users\username>taskkill /F /PID 3116
```

> Step 3:

```
Go to Eclipse and start Server , it will run
```

> OR

```
you can change port number in folder  servers>Tomcat>server.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

Open Command prompt with run as administrator and type **taskkill /F /PID 3100**
then it will terminate the process

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Co5Tg.png -- screenshot for Access is denied
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwZTv.png -- screenshot for successfully terminated