# Can't reach Tomcat UI after deploying website on DNS

Tags: tomcat, deployment, dns

I have recently bought a DNS and a VPS running on Ubuntu. I have installed Tomcat, phpmyadmin etc. on it and it has worked perfectly.
I used the IP address to reach the Tomcat UI, upload WAR files, use the database etc.
Ever since the DNS was forwarded to the IP address, and I removed the :8080 port at the end, I can't reach any of those services...
Before, it was

```
ip_adress:8080/appname
```

and then i changed it to

```
www.example.com
```

How can I reach those two? :(
They show a:

```
This site can’t be reached

    ip_adress took too long to respond.
    Search Google for xxxxxxxxx
    ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you configure your web app to launch on the default HTTP port (80) rather than the default Tomcat port (8080) then you will need to include the port number.

So your URL is probably something like www.example.com:8080/appname

It also sounds like you want to make your application (appname) the default application. Assuming your application is a servlet, you would also need to configure the appname servlet as the default servlet.

See these two previous answers:
[How to change tomcat port number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18415578/how-to-change-tomcat-port-number) and 
[Mapping a specific servlet to be the default servlet in Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14223150/mapping-a-specific-servlet-to-be-the-default-servlet-in-tomcat)