# How to use the browser to access tomcat on port 8080?

Tags: java, windows, tomcat, port

I have a remote server, and its default port is 8080, but you know the browser default use 80 port to access it, so can not access my tomcat.

How to configure it to access the tomcat's 8080 port?

It is under the windows.

If I use `www.example.com:8080` in the browser I can access the server, but if I use `www.example.com` I can not access it.

---

**EDIT**

I use Tomcat + IIS (Server Consolidation), IIS occupy the `80` port.

Comment: 'If I use www.example.com:8080 in the browser I can access the server, but if I use www.example.com I can not access it.' I agree. So what's the question?

Comment: @EJP yes, How can I use the `www.example.com` to access the tomcat(its default port is 8080, if I do not change the tomcat's port )?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot access the URL on `http://www.example.com` because the browser will try to make a TCP connection on port 80 while tomcat is listening to post 8080.

If you want to change the port tomcat is listening to, see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18415578/how-to-change-tomcat-port-number)

Another option is to use a proxy in front of your tomcat server. You can use apache web server or Nginx. They can listen to port 80 and forward your request to the tomcat server on port 8080.

**Update**

As mentioned in the comments below, as the post80 is already taken, adding reverse proxy cannot help. Because the reverse proxy will not be able to listen to port 80.

It is recommended to see which process is using port 80 and then a proper solution can be implemented.

**Update**

As IIS is listening on port 80, it is recommended to configure IIS to act as the reverse proxy.

You can follow this [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/friis/2016/08/25/setup-iis-with-url-rewrite-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-real-world-apps/) to do so.

Comment: @AmrEIAdawy The `80` port is be occupied. How to realize the 2rd method?

Comment: What do you mean by 'How to realize the 2rd method?' ?

Comment: @AmrEIAdawy The `80` port is be occupied. How to realize the 2rd method?

Comment: @AmrEIAdawy I mean this method: `use a proxy in front of your tomcat server. You can use apache web server or Nginx. They can listen to port 80 and forward your request to the tomcat server on port 8080`

Comment: See my EDIT. my friend , how to solve it if it is occupied by IIS?

Answer (score 0):

You can change tomcat connector port number.
Navigate to /tomcat-root/conf folder. Within you will find the server.xml file.

Open the server.xml and search for connector port and change it.

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" 
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

Comment: the 8443 is browser's default port? or the browser default port is 80 ?

Comment: 80 is the default