# Accessing Google Cloud VM Instance Tomcat using External IP

Tags: java, tomcat, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am trying to access my Tomcat HomePage which is inside my Google Cloud VM Instance with External IP address 35.189.85.127 and Internal IP 10.154.0.2. On my local machine, in my browser I tried http://35.189.85.127 and http://35.189.85.127:8080 but got error

> The connection has timed out. The server at 35.189.85.127 is taking too long to respond.

I have seen all the questions and replies on stackoverflow regarding this question but still I found no clear solution.

The steps that I've done so far:

1. I have setup a Google Cloud VM instance in Compute Engine. I am using Windows Server 2016 as the image.
2. Using RDP I log on to Windows Server.
3. I successfully installed Java 1.7 and Tomcat 7 on Windows Server.
4. I tested Java and Tomcat 7, both are working fine i.e. I open browser and type localhost:8080 and it shows Tomcat HomePage.
5. I replaced localhost with my VM Instance Internal IP i.e. 10.154.0.2:8080 and it again correctly shows Tomcat HomePage.
6. Now I try to access Tomcat HomePage using my VM Instance External IP (Static) 35.189.85.127 but in my browser I get error

> The connection has timed out. The server at 35.189.85.127 is taking too long to respond.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Faced the same issue today.

Noticed from your question that you're using an **Windows environment**.

## On Windows

Be sure that the Windows Firewall is properly configured to allow traffic under the ports you need (or deactivate it).

## On GCP

Under "VPC Network/Firewall Rules", create a new firewall rule and configure as below:

[Firewall Rule Parameters (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkDKG.png)

Or, you have the option to check the "Allow HTTP traffic" option under the Instance Configuration menu and edit Tomcat's server.xml to startup at port 80, as described here:

[Change Tomcat Port Tutorial @ StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18415578/how-to-change-tomcat-port-number)

Answer (score 0):

Option1: If it's just tomcat. GCP offers a click to launch Tomcat instance with an external IP. You can SSH and also have a temp tomcat username and password to manage any of your deployments. 
https://console.cloud.google.com/launcher/details/click-to-deploy-images/tomcat

Option 2:
If you wish to have a Google Cloud VM instance in Compute Engine.
You will need to setup security groups and assign it to your instance. 
Eg. Define rules to Open Tomcat port 8080(or any) externally / range. Assign that group/rule to your VM instance. 
There are many options available, it all depends on how you wish to organize things. You could create a VPC and add your instances there or keep them under the same subnet or have them accessible externally etc.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I really appreciate it. I think I will go with Option 2. But as per my name, I am a Newbie to Google Cloud. Could you guide me on how to go about this? We can also chat if its possible for you. Kindly let me know.

Comment: Hi Newbie, 

If wanted to go with Option 2 and have issues accessing with External IP.
Click on Google Cloud Platform -> VPC network -> Firewall rules. 
[This in AWS is called security groups]
Add an ingress rule. 
Give it a name, targets should be your Tomcat instance server / group of servers/Apply to all (you decide). 
Source IP rage would be 0.0.0.0/0 [as all external] and protocol would be "tcp 8080" [looking at your question, you set Tomcat port as 8080], allow this rule. 
And you should be set. 

and yes we can have a chat. IM / PM me the details.