# ERROR: Build step failed with exception org.codehaus.cargo.container.ContainerException: Failed to redeploy

Tags: java, git, maven, jenkins

I have Jenkins installed on my AWS EC2 server, on which the following are installed:

- Maven Integration Plugin
- Deploy to Container Plugin
- Slack Notification Plugin
- GitHub Integration Plugin

... and possibly a few others I cannot remember (because coding)...

I create new freestyle Project, go to its config, and do the following:

- In `General`, check `GitHub project`, and enter the Project url
- In `Source Code Management`, select `Git` and enter the Repository URL
- In `Build Triggers`, check `GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling`
- In Build, I add build step "Invoke top-level Maven targets", and do the following:

  - Enter `clean install` in `Goals`
  - Enter relative path of my project's `pom.xml` in `POM`
- In Post-build Actions, I do the following:

  - Archive the artifacts:
    [image]
  - Deploy war/ear to container:
    [image: idk what our business port is but from others, it was 8085]

On my attempt to build the (working) code, it fails, and I get this long stack of info on the console:

```
Started by user Mike Warren
Building in workspace /home/ec2-user/.jenkins/workspace/Project2
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/MikeWarren2014/171106-Project2-SHOULDi.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/MikeWarren2014/171106-Project2-SHOULDi.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/MikeWarren2014/171106-Project2-SHOULDi.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision d172c840db59d7aff020787e0b49f3741f57b555 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f d172c840db59d7aff020787e0b49f3741f57b555
Commit message: "gamification finished"
 > git rev-list --no-walk d172c840db59d7aff020787e0b49f3741f57b555 # timeout=10
[Project2] $ mvn -f SHOULDi-back/pom.xml clean install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building SHOULDi-back 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ SHOULDi-back ---
[INFO] Deleting /home/ec2-user/.jenkins/workspace/Project2/SHOULDi-back/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ SHOULDi-back ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ SHOULDi-back ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 49 source files to /home/ec2-user/.jenkins/workspace/Project2/SHOULDi-back/target/classes
[WARNING] /home/ec2-user/.jenkins/workspace/Project2/SHOULDi-back/src/main/java/com/zenith/DAO/UserDAO.java: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
[WARNING] /home/ec2-user/.jenkins/workspace/Project2/SHOULDi-back/src/main/java/com/zenith/DAO/UserDAO.java: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[WARNING] /home/ec2-user/.jenkins/workspace/Project2/SHOULDi-back/src/main/java/com/zenith/DAO/UserDAO.java: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
[WARNING] /home/ec2-user/.jenkins/workspace/Project2/SHOULDi-back/src/main/java/com/zenith/DAO/UserDAO.java: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ SHOULDi-back ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/ec2-user/.jenkins/workspace/Project2/SHOULDi-back/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ SHOULDi-back ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ SHOULDi-back ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.2:war (default-war) @ SHOULDi-back ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [SHOULDi-back] in [/home/ec2-user/.jenkins/workspace/Project2/SHOULDi-back/target/SHOULDi-back]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [/home/ec2-user/.jenkins/workspace/Project2/SHOULDi-back/src/main/webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [293 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: /home/ec2-user/.jenkins/workspace/Project2/SHOULDi-back/target/SHOULDi-back.war
[INFO] WEB-INF/web.xml already added, skipping
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ SHOULDi-back ---
[INFO] Installing /home/ec2-user/.jenkins/workspace/Project2/SHOULDi-back/target/SHOULDi-back.war to /home/ec2-user/.m2/repository/com/zenith/SHOULDi-back/1.0-SNAPSHOT/SHOULDi-back-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
[INFO] Installing /home/ec2-user/.jenkins/workspace/Project2/SHOULDi-back/pom.xml to /home/ec2-user/.m2/repository/com/zenith/SHOULDi-back/1.0-SNAPSHOT/SHOULDi-back-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 6.207 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-12-31T00:24:46+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 19M/48M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Archiving artifacts
Deploying /home/ec2-user/.jenkins/workspace/Project2/SHOULDi-back/target/SHOULDi-back.war to container Tomcat 7.x Remote with context Project2
ERROR: Build step failed with exception
org.codehaus.cargo.container.ContainerException: Failed to redeploy [/home/ec2-user/.jenkins/workspace/Project2/SHOULDi-back/target/SHOULDi-back.war]
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.redeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:192)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:77)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$DeployCallable.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:147)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$DeployCallable.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:117)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:997)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:975)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.redeploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:114)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.PasswordProtectedAdapterCargo.redeploy(PasswordProtectedAdapterCargo.java:93)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:64)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:744)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:690)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:186)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:635)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1749)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:421)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:242)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:339)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:357)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1220)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1156)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1050)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:984)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:561)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.list(TomcatManager.java:876)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.getStatus(TomcatManager.java:889)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.redeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:173)
    ... 17 more
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
```

How can I fix this?

My tomcat credentials, located in `[tomcat directory]/conf/tomcat-users.xml`, are as follows:

```
<tomcat-users>
        <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
        <role rolename="manager-script"/>
        <user username="tomcatgui" password="password" roles="manager-gui" />
        <user username="project2" password="Z3n1th0x47726f7570" roles="manager-script" />
</tomcat-users>
```

Comment: Are your tomcat details correct? Jenkins can't deploy the WAR to tomcat it seems.

Comment: I'm about to put the credentials of `tomcat/conf/tomcat-users.xml` here.

Comment: I didn't know what to put for context path...

Comment: The context path is the context path part of the URL under which your application will be published in Tomcat.

Comment: `java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)` indicate a firewall problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a connection time out,

1. Check whether you restarted the tomcat instance after editing the tomcat-users.xml
2. Check whether jenkins has access to tomcat instance.
3. Whether the user credentials are correct

Comment: The error I see upon viewing `[tomcat directory]/logs/catalina.out`: 

`SEVERE: StandardServer.await: create[localhost:8005]:
java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:387)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:375)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await(StandardServer.java:444)`

Comment: The port 8005 is used by someone else. So Tomcat cannot start. If you are on Linux, you can use `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep 8005` to check who is using the port. Stop that process (or change the tomcat start port - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18415578/how-to-change-tomcat-port-number) and try again.

Comment: I get the following: 

`tcp        0      0 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:8005       :::*                        LISTEN      4435/java
`

Comment: I have no idea what that is.

Comment: 4435 is the java process that uses the port 8005

Comment: I just typed `ps aux` on the console, and got this: 

`ec2-user  4435  0.0  9.0 2280596 91996 ?       Sl   00:21   0:34 /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_151/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/home/ec2-user/apache-tomcat-7.0.82/con`

Comment: I stopped that process, tried to rebuild, and still the same error

Answer (score 1):

For the same issue, setting port 8084 in `server.xml` and restarting the Apache worked for me. I replaced all occurrences of 8080 with 8084:

```
[root@ip-172-31-21-72 conf]# grep 8084 server.xml
     Define a non-SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8084
<Connector port="8084" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           port="8084" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
```

Answer (score 0):

comment tag **Valve** in **context.xml** files

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
allow="127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1" />
```

there are multiple context.xml files in tomcat directory, update following context.xml files and restart tomcat service-

- /apache-tomcat-8.5.41/webapps/manager/META-INF/context.xml
- /apache-tomcat-8.5.41/webapps/host-manager/META-INF/context.xml

Comment: ```<Context antiResourceLocking="false" privileged="true" docBase="${catalina.base}/webapps/manager">
<!--
  <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve" 
  allow="172\.16\.40\.41|127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1" />
-->
  <Manager sessionAttributeValueClassNameFilter="java\.lang\.(?:Boolean|Integer|Long|Number|String)|org\.apache\.catalina\.filters\.CsrfPreventionFilter\$LruCache(?:\$1)?|java\.util\.(?:Linked)?HashMap"/>
</Context>```

Comment: There is no `Valve` tag in my docker instance.

Answer (score 0):

1.If you are using public IP address in AWS/Azure/any Server. if we stop and start server there might be a chance of change in Public IP which we used to Deploy Our Container. Instead we can use Elastic IP.

2. To Redeploy Tomcat server if Public IP used then follow below steps
   Goto your Jenkins Dashboard:
   Manage Jenkins> configure>Post-build Actions
   --> Under Post build Actions change URL like Tomcat URL: http://ipa:8080
3. Restart tomcat server.
   `cd /opt/tomcat/bin/ && ./shutdown.sh`
   `cd /opt/tomcat/bin/ && ./startup.sh`
4. Open in Tomcat Manager Application.

Answer (score -1):

I GOT THE BUILD TO WORK!!!

**What I did**

In `[tomcat directory]/conf/server.xml`, I changed

```
 <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" />
```

to

```
<!-- my business port -->
<Connector port="8084" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" />
```

I then restart the Tomcat server, go to AWS EC2, only to realize there was no inbound rule for that business port! I created one, to accept connection from anywhere.

I then re-build the project. Upon trying to run the `.war` file, with

```
java -jar .jenkins/workspace/path/to/myProject.war
```

but get some issue about main (but this seems to be separate issue)...