# How to redirect rest requests from localhost:8080 to different port?

Tags: java, spring, rest, localhost

I have my spring web application which I can run with tomcat. My problem is, that I need to send all requests from application to different port that my tomcat is running on. Now tomcat is running on localhost:8080 and I want to send all request from my web application to different port for example localhost:8081. Can you give me some advice or is that even possible?

Want to change Request URL from [Actual Request URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQ4cD.png) (image) to this:  http://localhost:8081/pa165/lecture/list

Comment: Why not just use a location header? Do you control both applications? I'm confused about what the issue here is

Comment: See for port forwarding options for your OS if you really want to do so. Otherwise configure your application to use port 8081.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the correct answer of this question [How to change tomcat port number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18415578/how-to-change-tomcat-port-number)

You need to:

1. Go to tomcat>conf folder
2. Edit server.xml
3. Search "Connector port"
4. Replace "8080" by your port number
5. Restart tomcat server.

Comment: I find out that I am using tomcat plugin [look at image](https://prnt.sc/n3901u) and I know how to change port on which my tomcat is running, but I still can't fing out how to change the port for requests.

Comment: I saw you want to send requests to localhost:8081, do you have an API running or what?

Answer (score 1):

Simply document that 8081 is the port to connect to, just as you would have had to document that 8080 was the port to connect to.

If you didn't document that somewhere somehow for port 8080, how would any user/client know where to go ?  Ditto if your port is any other.