# Issue with apache tomcat server always running a program its showing that port 8080 is already used..?

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, apache, tomcat

Issue with apache tomcat server always running a program its showing that port 8080 is already used..

```
netstat -ano | findstr < Port Number >
taskkill /F /PID < Process Id >
```

I tried this every time that error is shown the problem is solved.

but has to done each time the server to be started or restarted.

I want a permanent solution to resolve this instead of each and every time manually stop the process in 8080..

Comment: Port 8080 required by Tomcat v8.0 Server at localhost is already in use. The server may already be running in another process, or a system process may be using the port. To start this server you will need to stop the other process or change the port number(s).

Answer (score 0):

you could either change the port of the other process to avoid a port conflict, or simply change it in tomcat

[How to change tomcat port number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18415578/how-to-change-tomcat-port-number)

and change it to something like 8081

Comment: i tried to change the port number to 8085...... so and so      But the same issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a service automatically starts on each startup, have you had a look between your services which automatically restarts?

You can have a look which executable is running on which port with following command (needs admin privileges):

```
netstat -a -b
```

Got the command from here:
[How can you find out which process is listening on a port on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198/how-can-you-find-out-which-process-is-listening-on-a-port-on-windows)

and you should have an output like this:

```
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8080           WS1515:0               LISTENING
 [java.exe]
```

This should give already a hint which process automatically start on each startup, you can have a look in the service tab (you open a run window and input services.msc and press enter)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using netstat, I believe you are using Windows. There are two ways in which you can handle the issue:

1. Disable tomcat service that is running by checking in services.msc. You can change the mode of startup from automatic to manual. This usually happens when you have installed a software using an msi that installs the tomcat service as a part of it.
2. You can try to change your tomcat server port by editing the following lines in the /conf/server.xml:

```
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443"/>
```

Change `port = 8080` to something else like `port = 8082`. In that way, you can continue using the customized tomcat without harming any other essential service that has been installed as mentioned in point #1 above