# Camunda platform tomcat server on port 8080 opens jenkins. so that unable to run camunda platform in my ubuntu system

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, port, camunda, business-process-management

Unable to connect the camunda platform if the jenkins server is installed. I am trying to change the port 8080 of camunda platform. but i did not find the resource to change the port. Please help me to resolve this

Edit [solution]:

For changing the port of tomcat => [How to change Apache Tomcat web server port number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18415578/how-to-change-apache-tomcat-web-server-port-number)

after changing the port site says not found then i checked the logs in tomcat server. find out the issue. the issue is jdbc is occupied by another one in my system. then i kill the process and started the camunda works fine.

Comment: On https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18415578/how-to-change-apache-tomcat-web-server-port-number it is explained how to change port number on a tomcat server.

Comment: Thank you for the info. after changing the port. url says site not found. after checking the logs in tomcat. it says the java jdbc is already used by another one in my system. after that i kill the process and started the camunda then works fine.